# Notification layout html using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I need to build a grid for a custom notification layout but I cannot understand how to do. Currently i'm using bootstrap css to create it.

The result should be as follow (the number above is the column size in bootstrap):

[image]

My code is the follow:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <img ...>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <div>Text 1</div>
        <div>Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <img ...>
        <img ...>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the last column aren't you? You need one more:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
```

See here: http://www.bootply.com/8rl3F6ETs6

I have changed how the second column is laid out to make it more explicit, but I believe if what you're going for is two columns on the right, you just need to add another column.

And add the class .text-center to each column div if you want the content centered.